# Rebuilding all normal indexes for a specific Oracle table

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

We have a migration script that converts a LONG column to a LOB, and as mentioned in the [Oracle migration guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14249/adlob_long_lob.htm#i1021732), the index for the table now needs rebuilding.

Assuming the table name is `MY_TABLE`, I've been attempting to run this script:

```
BEGIN
    FOR index_entry IN (
        select INDEX_NAME from user_indexes where table_name='MY_TABLE' and index_type='NORMAL'
    )
    LOOP
        ALTER INDEX index_entry.index_name REBUILD;
    END LOOP;
END;
```

However, it fails with the following syntax error:

```
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "ALTER" when expecting one of the following:

   ( begin case declare exit for goto if loop mod null pragma
   raise return select update while with <an identifier>
   <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable> <<
   continue close current delete fetch lock insert open rollback
   savepoint set sql execute commit forall merge pipe purge
 [Failed SQL: BEGIN
                FOR index_entry IN (
                    select INDEX_NAME from user_indexes where table_name='MY_TABLE' and index_type='NORMAL'
                )
                LOOP
                    ALTER INDEX index_entry.index_name REBUILD]
```

Even though this *seems* to match the syntax specified here: [Database PL/SQL Language Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/static.htm#CHDBJBJE)

Is `ALTER` not a valid command to use in a loop?

**Edit:** At *lad2025*'s suggestion, attempting to use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` like so:

```
5: LOOP
6:     execute immediate 'alter index ' || index_entry.index_name || ' rebuild';
7: END LOOP;
```

I receive:

```
ORA-06550: line 6, column 92:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:

   * & = - + ; < / > at in is mod remainder not rem return
   returning <an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or
   like like2 like4 likec between into using || bulk member
   submultiset

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:439)
```

**Edit 2:** The `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` worked properly. The end-of-file issue was related to Liquibase executing my script, and my forgetting to define my `<sql>` block with:

```
<sql dbms="oracle" splitStatements="false">
                                    ^ defaults to true
```

Critically, Liquibase by default splits statements at the semicolon, and this needed to be turned off.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You cannot use DDL statements in PL/SQL block. Use Dynamic-SQL:

```
BEGIN
    ...
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER INDEX ' || index_entry.INDEX_NAME || ' REBUILD';
END
```

**EDIT:**

Try:

```
DECLARE
BEGIN
    FOR index_entry IN (select INDEX_NAME 
                        from user_indexes 
                        where  table_name='MY_TABLE' and
                         index_type='NORMAL')
    LOOP
        dbms_output.put_line('ALTER INDEX ' || index_entry.INDEX_NAME || ' REBUILD'); 
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER INDEX ' || index_entry.INDEX_NAME || ' REBUILD';
    END LOOP;
END;
/
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0f6d2/13/0)**</kbd>

Comment: Question updated - I gave that a try, but received a new error related to `end-of-file` found, but not expected.

Comment: Thanks - I've tried a few different combinations of syntax, but none have worked yet. (Despite every indication in the docs that they _should_.)

Comment: Thanks - that works! My end-of-file issue was a Liquibase configuration problem, and I updated my question.